# Django отобразить админку

Tags: django

Помогите пожалуйста настроить ссылки на index.html по адресу мой_домен.ru и на страницу входа в админку по адресу мой_домен.ru/admin
Здесь работает только index.html и админка открывается по этому же адресу

**urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('', include('broom.urls')),
]
urlpatterns += static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

**broom/urls.py**

```
urlpatterns = [
url('', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

Comment: *Здесь работает только index.html и админка открывается по этому же адресу* поясните.

Comment: ну то есть я ввожу в адресную строку домен, открывается индексная страница, ввожу домен.ru/admin и открывается та же индексная страница

Answer (score 0):

решение

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('broom/', include('broom.urls')),
    path('', RedirectView.as_view(url='/broom/', permanent=True)),
]
```